# How to fix white space in bootstrap row with responsive image in IE11?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4

I have a img in a column in a row (i'm using React):

```
<div className="row">
  <div className="col-md-12 ">
    <img src={headerImage} className="img-fluid"/>
  </div>
</div>
```

When using this code in IE11 and when I resize the window, the image is being resized correctly. However, the original height is still there (the height of the image). So I see the image resized correctly, but the row where the image is in, has white space in it, since it won't adjust to the height of the image.

How can this be resolved?

Comment: Try `vertical-align: top` on image.

Comment: @NenadVracar Nothing happens when applying that code to the img element.

Comment: @G-Cyr Unfortunately not..